# Events of $.ajax, how to create a callback?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, coffeescript

I know that the title was not very intuitive, so I'll try to detail my problem:

I am creating a jQuery plugin to make asynchronous calls.
With it I can for example make a post using the following command:

```
$("form").bindAjaxPost "post"
```

The problem is that I would like to create callbacks for these events (`beforeSend`, `complete`, `success`, `error`), for example, the command would look something like:

```
$("form").bindAjaxPost "post", 
    success: (data) -> console.log "user success #{data}"
    beforeSend: () -> console.log "user beforeSend"
```

Notice that the event `beforeSend` and `success` was defined by the user of the plugin and also internally in the plugin code: See the code:

**Method post jquery plugin**

```
post: (ajaxUserOptions)-> 

    ajaxOptions = 
        type: "POST"
        url: @options.url
        data: $(@form).serialize()
        dataType: @options.dataType

        beforeSend: ->
            console.log "plugin beforeSend"

        complete: ->
            console.log "plugin complete"

        success: (data) ->
            console.log "plugin success"

        error: (request) ->
            console.log "plugin error"


    ajaxOptions = $.extend {}, ajaxUserOptions, ajaxOptions if ajaxUserOptions
    $.ajax(ajaxOptions)
```

### Problem

I would like the event success, should be called internally, and then the user-defined event plugin. (this sequence)

### Execution example

**Command**

```
$("form").bindAjaxPost "post", 
    success: (data) -> console.log "user success #{data}"
    beforeSend: () -> console.log "user beforeSend"
```

**Output**

plugin beforeSend
user beforeSend
plugin success
user success

### Attempts

As you can see in the code, I tried to use the command `extend` of jQuery. But it did not work because the `$.ajax().beforeSend` accepts only one function.

I also tried to access the `ajaxUserOptions` but `ajaxUserOptions` is not available in the events `success`, `beforeSend`..., since these calls are asynchronous.

**Thank you all for your help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this to be easier to implement using the Promise interface added to the return value of `$.ajax` in jQuery 1.5. With that, you can attach multiple `complete`, `success`, and `error` callbacks (preferably as `always`, `done`, and `fail`, as the former names will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8.) So your code might become

```
    post: (ajaxUserOptions = {}) -> 

        defaultAjaxOptions =
            type: "POST"
            url: @options.url
            data: $(@form).serialize()
            dataType: @options.dataType

        jqXHR = $.ajax($.extend {}, ajaxUserOptions, defaultAjaxOptions)
        jqXHR.always pluginAlways
        jqXHR.always ajaxUserOptions.always if ajaxUserOptions.always
        # and likewise for fail and done
```

`beforeSend` is a trickier case, since you can't do that on the jqXHR object, but it's just a matter of wrapping your plugin's function and the user's function in a single function where, if either function returns `false`, the outer function does so (since this stops the Ajax request):

```
beforeSend = ->
  return false if pluginBeforeSend() is false
  return false if ajaxUserOptions?.beforeSend() is false
```

Comment: I will study the `Promise interface`.   About the `beforeSend ` event. The problem is that I do not have access to the object `ajaxUserOptions`.   Because the call is asynchronous, the object `ajaxUserOptions` is only available in the `post` method.

Comment: Right, I was suggesting defining the `beforeSend` wrapper inside of the `post` method and adding it to the object passed to `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you call the user supplied callbacks from inside your plug-in if they exist? Similar to this:

```
post: (ajaxUserOptions)-> 

  ajaxOptions = 
    type: "POST"
    url: @options.url
    data: $(@form).serialize()
    dataType: @options.dataType

    beforeSend: ->
      console.log "plugin beforeSend"
      ajaxUserOptions.beforeSend() if ajaxUserOptions?.beforeSend?

    complete: ->
      console.log "plugin complete"

    success: (data) ->
      console.log "plugin success"
      ajaxUserOptions.success(data) if ajaxUserOptions?.success?

    error: (request) ->
      console.log "plugin error"

    $.ajax(ajaxOptions)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it. See the question, where I talk about my **attempts**.  The problem is that I do not have access to the object ajaxUserOptions. Because the call is asynchronous, the object ajaxUserOptions is only available in the post method.